# algorithm to figure out how many bytes are required to hold an int

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

sorry for the stupid question, but how would I go about figuring out, mathematically or using c++, how many bytes it would take to store an integer.

Comment: `int HowManyBytesToStoreAnInteger() { return sizeof(int); }`  Or did you mean something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine how many bytes an integer needs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274428/how-to-determine-how-many-bytes-an-integer-needs)

Comment: @rob I meant if you were given a number (say 700) how many bytes would you need to store that number (2).

Comment: What exactly do you mean?  How many bytes does it take to store any value from 0 to N?  Any value from -N to N?  To represent a number N in a way so that the bytes can be uniquely converted back to the number N?  Are the four bytes `{0, 0, 0, 1}` different from the two bytes `{0, 1}`?  etc.

Comment: What do you want the `sizeof(int)` does not provide?

Answer (score 11):

If you mean from an [information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) point of view, then the easy answer is:

```
log(number) / log(2)
```

(It doesn't matter if those are natural, binary, or common [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm), because of the division by `log(2)`, which calculates the logarithm with base `2`.)

This reports the number of bits necessary to store your number.

If you're interested in how much memory is required for the *efficient* or *usual* encoding of your number in a specific language or environment, you'll need to do some research. :)

The typical C and C++ ranges for integers are:

```
 char    1 byte
 short   2 bytes
 int     4 bytes
 long    8 bytes
```

If you're interested in arbitrary-sized integers, [special libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) are available, and every library will have its own internal storage mechanism, but they'll typically store numbers via 4- or 8- byte chunks up to the size of the number.

Comment: almost - you need to round up to the nearest multiple of 8, since he asked for how many bytes

Comment: `log(number)` has trouble with `number <= 0`.  Why use `log(number) / log(2)` at that has trouble with values near powers of 2:  `log(number)` and `log(2)` only provides approximately correct answers.  Seems better to use `log2(number)` instead.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it depends on the tools you've got available to you; some systems have base 10 and base e logs but not base 2 logs. There's lots of tools available if you don't have any of these to work with: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious

Answer (score 9):

You could find the first power of 2 that's larger than your number, and divide that power by 8, then round the number up to the nearest integer. So for 1000, the power of 2 is 1024 or 2^10; divide 10 by 8 to get 1.25, and round up to 2. You need two bytes to hold 1000!

Comment: You can even convert to binary and check how many bits or bytes it can take

Comment: "first power of 2 that's larger than your number" has trouble for values near `INT_MAX` and `i < 0`.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean "how large is an int" then `sizeof(int)` is the answer.

If you mean "how small a type can I use to store values of this magnitude" then that's a bit more complex. If you already have the value in integer form, then presumably it fits in 4, 3, 2, or 1 bytes. For unsigned values, if it's 16777216 or over you need 4 bytes, 65536-16777216 requires 3 bytes, 256-65535 needs 2, and 0-255 fits in 1 byte. The formula for this comes from the fact that each byte can hold 8 bits, and each bit holds 2 digits, so 1 byte holds 2^8 values, ie. 256 (but starting at 0, so 0-255). 2 bytes therefore holds 2^16 values, ie. 65536, and so on.

You can generalise that beyond the normal 4 bytes used for a typical int if you like. If you need to accommodate signed integers as well as unsigned, bear in mind that 1 bit is effectively used to store whether it is positive or negative, so the magnitude is 1 power of 2 less.

You can calculate the number of bits you need iteratively from an integer by dividing it by two and discarding the remainder. Each division you can make and still have a non-zero value means you have one more bit of data in use - and every 8 bits you're using means 1 byte.

A quick way of calculating this is to use the shift right function and compare the result against zero.

```
int value = 23534; // or whatever
int bits = 0;

while (value)
{
    value >> 1;
    ++bits;
}
std::cout << "Bits used = " << bits << std::endl;
std::cout << "Bytes used = " << (bits / 8) + 1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is exactly what i meant. Thanks for an easy solution.

Comment: Each byte holds `CHAR_BIT` bits, not 8 bits.

Comment: Voted up for accuracy Sharptooth, although I'd hope that anybody writing C++ on a system that doesn't have an 8 bit char already knows how to calculate this sort of thing. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is basically the same question as "how many binary digits would it take to store a number *x*?" All you need is the logarithm.

A *n*-bit integer can store numbers up to 2<sup>n</sup>-1. So, given a number *x*, ceil(log<sub>2</sub> *x*) gets you the number of digits you need.

It's exactly the same thing as figuring out how many decimal digits you need to write a number by hand. For example, log<sub>10</sub> 123456 = 5.09151220... , so ceil( log<sub>10</sub>(123456) ) = 6, six digits.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody put up the simplest code that works yet, I mind as well do it:

```
unsigned int get_number_of_bytes_needed(unsigned int N) {
  unsigned int bytes = 0;
  while(N) { 
    N >>= 8;
    ++bytes;
  };
  return bytes;
};
```

Comment: It should be `CHAR_BIT`, not 8.

Comment: I one thinks `get_number_of_bytes_needed(0)`should return 1, a `do {.... while while(N);` will handle that.

Answer (score 1):

assuming `sizeof(long int) = 4`.

```
int nbytes( long int x )
{
  unsigned long int n = (unsigned long int) x;

  if (n <= 0xFFFF)
  {
    if (n <= 0xFF) return 1;
    else return 2;
  }
  else
  {
    if (n <= 0xFFFFFF) return 3;
    else return 4;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The *shortest code* way to do this is as follows:

```
int bytes = (int)Math.Log(num, 256) + 1;
```

The code is small enough to be inlined, which helps offset the "slow" FP code. Also, there are no branches, which can be expensive.

Comment: Wouldn't +1 and floor sometimes, in the case that the log produces a whole number) result in an over-generous result?  Ceiling is the more correct operation, no?  e.g.
int bytes = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log(num, 256));

Comment: Nope, it's correct. You can test it in Excel or via code. E.g. Log(256,256) = 1, with +1 = 2, which is correct. Log (255, 256) is ~0.99 = 0 + 1 = 1, which is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * assumes i is non-negative.
 * note that this returns 0 for 0, when perhaps it should be special cased?
 */
int numberOfBytesForNumber(int i) {
    int bytes = 0;
    int div = 1;
    while(i / div) {
        bytes++;
        div *= 256;
    }
    if(i % 8 == 0) return bytes;
    return bytes + 1;
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. For example, 1024/256 is 4, exactly, but the correct answer is 2.

Comment: @Ernest thanks - fixed (i think, i'm in a dungeon right now, can't check it haha).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
// works for num >= 0
int numberOfBytesForNumber(int num) {
   if (num < 0)
      return 0;
   else if (num == 0)
      return 1;
   else if (num > 0) {
      int n = 0;
      while (num != 0) {
        num >>= 8;
        n++;
      }
      return n;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code runs at 447 million tests / sec on my laptop where `i` = 1 to 1E9. `i` is a signed int:

```
n = (i > 0xffffff || i < 0) ? 4 : (i < 0xffff) ? (i < 0xff) ? 1 : 2 : 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Python example: no logs or exponents, just bit shift.

**Note:** `0` counts as 0 bits and only positive `int`s are valid.

```py
def bits(num):
    """Return the number of bits required to hold a int value."""
    if not isinstance(num, int):
        raise TypeError("Argument must be of type int.")
    if num < 0:
        raise ValueError("Argument cannot be less than 0.")

    for i in count(start=0):
        if num == 0:
            return i
        num = num >> 1
```